# How to add a bold text in Rich TextBox programatically using VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, richtextbox

I have this code:

```
print_text.Text = "Patient number: " + ds.Tables("patients").Rows(0).Item(0)
print_text.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
print_text.Text = print_text.Text + "Last name: " + ds.Tables("patients").Rows(0).Item(1)
print_text.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
```

Now the above data i am adding programatically and it works fine. However in the above code i want to add `Patient number` and `Last name` in bold font.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using a `RichTextBox`, why not just use RTF?

---

**Example:**

```
Sub Main
    Dim f = new Form()
    Dim print_text = new RichTextBox() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
    f.Controls.Add(print_text)

    Dim sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("{\rtf1\ansi")
    sb.Append("This number is bold: \b 123\b0 ! Yes, it is...")
    sb.Append("}")
    print_text.Rtf = sb.ToString()

    f.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image: RichTextBox with bold text]

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287595%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

---

This way, you can also easily wrap the RTF stuff into extension methods:

```
Module RtfExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToRtf(s As String) As String
        Return "{\rtf1\ansi" + s + "}"
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToBold(s As String) As String
        Return String.Format("\b {0}\b0 ", s)
    End Function

End Module
```

and use it like

```
Dim text = "This number is bold: " + "123".ToBold() + "! Yes, it is..."
print_text.Rtf = text.ToRtf()
```

Comment: Nice and neat solution, I like it.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `RichTextBox.SelectionFont` Property.
Check these MSDN Links on how to do this: [Link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont.aspx#Y253) and [Link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh8963yx.aspx)

Hope it helps.
**EDIT:**

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim len As Integer
    RichTextBox1.Text = "Patient number: " + " 12345"
    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
    RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = "Patient number".Length
    RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
    len = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
    RichTextBox1.AppendText("Last name: " + " ABCD")
    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = len
    RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = "Last name".Length
    RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: This is for a selected text. What i want is that the data i am adding dynamically to the rich Textbox should be in bold font

Comment: Its not about dynamic or static. You can use this property in any place but will need to use it appropriately. I have updated my answer to include a simple example. Please have a look. Thanks.