# Add partially bolded text to a richtextbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I am using a Rich Text Box as a display log for my program. The program preforms a mass copy of one directory from a source machine to multiple target machines. I wish to bold the computer name as added to the the text box as I add the lines. I currently add the lines as follows:

```
rtbStatusLog.AppendText(My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToString + " " + TargetName + ": File Copied: " + destinationFileName + vbCrLf)
```

I need the "Target Name" variable, and subsequent: to be bold, but nothing else.

I also wish to do this as the lines are added if possible instead of selecting the results at the end and bolding them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a bold text in Rich TextBox programatically using VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775387/how-to-add-a-bold-text-in-rich-textbox-programatically-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

A rich text box has a property called `SelectionFont`. Setting attributes of this property changes the way the text is shown.

So do it like this:

```
Dim currentFont As System.Drawing.Font = rtbStatusLog.SelectionFont
Dim newFontStyle As System.Drawing.FontStyle

rtbStatusLog.SelectedText = My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.ToString
rtbStatusLog.SelectionFont = New Font(currentFont.FontFamily,currentFont.Size,newFontStyle) 
rtbStatusLog.SelectedText = " " + TargetName + ": File Copied: " + destinationFileName + vbCrLf)
```

When you change the `SelectedText` property you are actually writing to the box.

[Reference SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Reference SelectionFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)